# Log commands executed in ubuntu

Tags: command-line

Is there a way to monitor commands that are executed on an ubuntu system? basically i am looking for something like a key logger but only for commands executed.

Comment: Are you looking for your commands or for commands from all users? Or even only for your commands for a specific session (e.g. see `script`)? If you are looking on spying on other users, then please realise that I used the term *spying*.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that you could look into the BASH history file? From the BASH MAN page "On startup, the history is initialized from the file named by the variable HISTFILE (default ~/.bash_history)."