# How do I monitor rm, mv , mkdir commands in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: command-line

I want to monitor the `rm`, `mv` and `mkdir` commands in Ubuntu Server.

How could this be achieved?

Comment: What do you mean by monitoring those commands? You want to see their progresses while operating?

Comment: I don't think there would be any progress to see for `mkdir`, so the question must be about logging.

Comment: you can use `-v` option to see what `rm` and `mv` are doing...

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what exact behavior do you want, what kind of monitoring do you expect. If it is closed before you can edit it, please still make an edit and leave a comment. Moderators and higher-rep users can vote to reopen the question

Comment: I need to know, in ubntu server, who is using rm command on which file/dir.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log commands executed in ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/349126/log-commands-executed-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @DSivaKumar if you want to provide more information please [edit] your question, don't use a comment for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to log the usage of these commands, you could make some shell scripts to wrap them.

For example, for `rm`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $(date +"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S") $USER: $0 $@ >> /tmp/rm.log
/bin/rm.real $@
```

Assuming you named this file `rm_log.sh`, you install it like this:

```
$ sudo mv -n /bin/rm /bin/rm.real
$ sudo cp rm_log.sh /bin/rm
```

Now whenever someone uses the `rm` command, you get a new line in the `/tmp/rm.log` file. For example:

```
$ rm example.txt
$ cat /tmp/rm.log
12-28-2015 12:34:56 cos64: /bin/rm example.txt
```